# How to match ambiguous path and static path with React Router

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am currently trying to match the following URL

```
https://www.example.com/discover/exampleuser/review
```

there are other urls that i am matching with regex as well

```
https://www.example.com/discover/community
https://www.example.com/discover/reviews
https://www.example.com/discover/activity
```

I have the following code that will match the last three urls fine

```
<Route path={`${url}/(community|reviews|activity)`} render={prop => (
  <div className='mb-4'>
    <CollectionWidget { ...prop } />
  </div>
)} />
```

Whenever I use the following path it works

```
{`${url}/:username`}
```

however when i try to match all of the urls like so it does not

```
{`${url}/(community|reviews|activity|:username)`}
```

How do i match regex with a ambiguous id

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the wildcard in as a variable? `{`${url}/(community|reviews|activity|${:username})`}` Does that help?

Comment: so is `match.params.user` just silently ignored in target component? if there are `if ... else ...` inside the component it'd be better to refactor all that into 2 separate components bound to different(parametrized and without parameters) routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds impossible to be honest, how could you match both unnamed and named parameter at the same time?

Good thing you could pass in 2 strings (or more):

```
<Route 
  path={[
    `${base}/(a|b|c)`, 
    `${base}/:username
  `]} 
  component={({ match }) => <div children={JSON.stringify(match.params)} />} />

// /b ---> { 0: "b" }
// /c ---> { 0: "c" }
// /d ---> { "username": "d" }
```